# Looking for a pre-made (commercial or not) PHP tool for managing a directory of images, with some specific features

Tags: php, image-management

I'm developing an administrative panel to manage product listings. The database structure is already done and it takes me no effort to make a little panel where administrative users will insert and remove products. But every product has a variable number of images that should to be uploaded by the administrative user. Doing a good work will take me some hours, and I have absolutely no time. So I need something pre-made that will let the administrative user:

- upload the photos of the product, in a certain server directory (passed as a parameter, for example)
- delete one or more photos (preferably with a checkbox to select some of them and then a "delete" button)
- show the thumbnails of the currently uploaded photos
- **sort** the photos (I understand that's quite an high request, because sorting means renaming the files!), *preferably* in an intuitive way (drag & drop, etc...).

It would be awesome if the script could be *seamlessly* included in an another script without using iframes.

**Why don't I just Google for it?** That's because I would have to try all the stuff around (when 90% of it is ugly) and I hope you already know a good script *you have tested yourself* that can work in my scenario!

I've already considered Gallery3, it might work, but it is overkill and hard to integrate. I don't need album creation and management, per-user permissions, or photo showcase and slideshow, what I need it's basically a tiny file manager tailored for images.

There's little time for hiring a developer online, it would take too much to get "in tune" with him/her...

Comment: saving them in a database gives you an easier option to order them. The other options you're requesting are not really hard for an average developer. You could take a look at `codecanyon.net` there are quiet a couple image managers, it's worth looking if there's something that meets your requirements there.

Comment: An average developer which am I, but it has to be ready for tomorrow!

Comment: Not really any other options if you don't want to spend time getting in tune with a developer. Have you took a look at codecanyon.net already? They have simpel tools for uploading/thumbnailing etc. Only part you have to do is getting them in the database and ordering team (drag & drop is just a bonus imo, simpel +- buttons would work aswel).

Comment: @PENDO: in that website I found a script which does quite exactly what I need, it just needs some tweaks. Thanks. That site sells quality stuff. Please delete your comment, post an answer so that I can rate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `http://www.codecanyon.net`, they might have scripts that fit your needs over 80% and just need little modifications.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how many of your criteria [jAlbum](http://jalbum.net/) meets, but it might be worth a look. Someone I know has used it extensively with success.

Another one I'm less familiar with, but might suit, is [Plogger](http://www.plogger.org/).

Of course, with the deadline you were facing, you have probably already sorted this by now! :)

Comment: +1 Good suggestion, but solved with Simple Gallery found on http://www.codecanyon.net